# How can I hook windows microphone settings to keep other applications from changing it

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

The voice chat application is always automatically changing the microphone settings and cannot be stopped. So I just want to make something that can lock it. I only found the windows message hooking in Windows APIs but it is not likely to work on audio settings. Is there any way to hook any change on audio settings instead of briefly changing it?

Comment: Stop running voice chat?  I uninstalled my microphone and camera drivers, that pretty much solved the problem with updates raining down and re-enabling things.

Comment: the purpose of everything is to prevent the voice settings from changing while using the voice chat application. If nothing is running, there would be naturally not any change on the settings, and this question would be meaningless. @jwdonahue

Comment: What good is voice chat without a microphone?

Comment: @jwdonahue No you misunderstood the problem, the voice chat keeps setting the microphone volume to 50% and this can't be stopped by its configuration. I do want it to access the microphone but all I want to do is banning it from setting the microphone volume